# What form of energy creates heat during combustion?

Tags: infrared-radiation, combustion

We know that energy is released during oxidation but it is not clear what form it takes initially. I read the energy of chemical bonds of the fuel is not much different from that of the product, so it must be something else.
Is it then EM radiation, mostly infrared? That would have the capability of generating much heat although it seems too slow a form of energy to produce so much heat in so little time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have misinterpreted what you read - functionally all of the energy released during a typical chemical reaction comes from the rearrangement of electrons.

Part of this can be attributed to the difference in energy stored in the atomic bonds, and the rest can be accounted for by e.g. the transfer of electrons between atoms of different electronegativity (redox reactions).

When the identities of some of the nuclei change over the course of the reaction, this provides another source of energy which originates in the nucleus.

Comment: So the movement of electrons makes the molecules move too (bumps them around) and this is what creates thermal movement of all the molecules involved? Sounds plausible.

Comment: @stevie In a manner of speaking.  Don't think about the "movement of electrons" as though they are solid spheres rattling around, though - instead, just note that for a collection of atoms and molecules, there are multiple possible arrangements of electrons which bind the molecules together in different ways.  If you transition from a loosely-bound, high-energy arrangement to a tightly-bound, low-energy arrangement, the excess energy at the end will go into heating the product, and your reaction will be exothermic; if the reverse is true, your reaction will be endothermic.